# JavaMail silently fails

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use JavaMail on a web application, my mail properties file looks like this:

`mail.host=...
mail.user=...
mail.password=...
mail.from=...
mail.smtp.host=...
mail.smtp.user=...
mail.smtp.password=...`

And then I'm using:

```
mailSession=Session.getDefaultInstance(mailProps);
```

For some reason, the call fails. I see no error in the logs, so I can't tell what the exact problem is, but the server returns 500.

Does someone have any idea what I'm missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: No chance to check the logs of the server? Any reasonable implementation should log something or provide an error code. It might not be in the normal logs though, some servers have an error log or similar.

Comment: As I said, I saw nothing in the logs. I'm using Tomcat 7.

Comment: `mail.store.protocol` and `mail.smtp.port` is missing. I have working code in which i found those two extra properties.

Comment: I just need to send e-mails, so I don't need store, and the port has a default value.

Comment: try setting mail.debug property to true.

Comment: May be firewall is blocking your request. Just make sure your default port is open for incoming and outgoing connections

Comment: I seem to recall that this occurs if your mail.from is not valid.  I can't remember whether a valid value is a server-recognized account, or a value that matches the hostname of the sender (your program) when the server does a reverse DNS lookup.

Comment: The getDefaultInstance call is failing?  How do you know?  What exception is it throwing?  You want to [use getInstance instead](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#getdefaultinstance) anyway.  And enable [JavaMail Session debugging](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to find out what's going wrong.